# Combine js & css: how to deal with relative paths?

Tags: javascript, css, relative-path

I have a php system, where the view objects can inlcude css and js files via a core function. The system combines all the included js and css files to a min.css and min.js and the site will use that two.
The problem is, that the files contains relative paths and the minified ones are at another location, so I have a bunch of broken links. I can write absolute paths, but when I load some third party library, the problem will occur (and I don't want to overwrite them obviously).
Now I simply don't use this method for the libs, but I wonder that there are any good solution for this kind of problem?

Comment: you should put combined/compressed files in same path than the originals

Comment: I can't do that, because I combine all the js files on the site into 1 file, so the "original" is actually 5-6 location.

Comment: Maybe you should consider putting them in same path..

Comment: I can't guarantee that there is no collision in 2 lib's filenames, therefore I can't just put them in the same directory. And of course it would be a chaos...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should Do something like this:

```
<script>
   var base_url = <?=get_base_url();?>
</script>
<script type="text/css" src="js/compressed.js"></script>
```

And in `compressed.js`, use absolute path's like this:

(for example, an ajax call):

```
$.get( base_url + 'path/file' , function(data){});
```

The thing is that with this solution you will have to refactor the code..

Comment: I can't refactor the libraries, but of course this is a good solution for my code.